# prevent creation of users with permissions higher than the entity who has created it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I added a `permission boundary` to  `user1` with only `IAMFullAccess` allow actions. works fine. Then `user1` created `user2` with same permission boundary and `AdministratorAccess` permission policy. I am expecting `user2` to have only as much permissions as `user1` (i.e. only IAM), but it has all permissions.
How to prevent creation of users with permissions higher than the entity who has created it?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
              "iam:*"
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "DenyRemovalOfBoundary",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": [
              "iam:DeleteUserPermissionsBoundary",
              "iam:DeleteRolePermissionsBoundary"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/*",
              "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/*"
          ],
          "Condition": {
              "StringEquals": {
                  "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:policy/oktaDeveloperPermissionsBoundary"
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "Sid": "NoBoundaryPolicyEditOrDelete",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": [
              "iam:DeletePolicy",
              "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
              "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
              "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:policy/oktaDeveloperPermissionsBoundary"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "DenyCreationWithoutPermBoundary",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": [
              "iam:CreateRole",
              "iam:CreateUser"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/*",
              "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/*"
          ],
          "Condition": {
              "StringNotEquals": {
                  "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:policy/oktaDeveloperPermissionsBoundary"
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "Sid": "DenyAccessIfPermBoundaryIsNotBeingApplied",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": [
              "iam:PutUserPermissionsBoundary",
              "iam:PutRolePermissionsBoundary"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:user/*",
              "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/*"
          ],
          "Condition": {
              "StringNotEquals": {
                  "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:policy/oktaDeveloperPermissionsBoundary"
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "Sid": "DenyReservedCapacityPurchasesDynamoDB",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": "dynamodb:PurchaseReservedCapacityOfferings",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:ACCOUNT:*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "DenyReservedCapacityPurchasesRDS",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": [
              "rds:PurchaseReservedDBInstancesOffering"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:ACCOUNT:*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "DenyReservedCapacityPurchasesEC2",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": [
              "ec2:PurchaseHostReservation",
              "ec2:PurchaseReservedInstancesOffering",
              "ec2:PurchaseScheduledInstances"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:ACCOUNT:*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "limitedSize",
          "Effect": "Deny",
          "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
          "Condition": {
              "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                  "ec2:InstanceType": [
                      "m5.16xlarge",
                      "t3.nano"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

I understand this may be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267341/aws-permission-boundary-wont-apply-to-the-secound-user) but I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: Use a [permission boundary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html).